# Assign section of variable to another variable in Perl using regexp

Tags: regex, perl

If I had

```
my $ip = "10.9.8.X";
```

and I want $IPCore to have "10.9.8". Is there an easy way to do this in a single line?

I usually do this

```
my $ip = "10.9.8.X";
my $IPCore = $ip;
$IPCore =~ s/([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3})\.[xX]{1,3}$/$1/

##$IPCore is now 10.9.8
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution to remove the last `.` and everything after it:

```
( my $IPCore = $ip ) =~ s/\.[^.]*\z//;
my $IPCore = $ip =~ s/\.[^.]*\z//r;                        # 5.14+
```

Optimized solution to remove the third `.` and everything after it:

```
( my $IPCore = $ip ) =~ s/^[^.]*+(?:\.[^.]*+){2}\K.*//s;   # 5.10+
my $IPCore = $ip =~ s/^[^.]*+(?:\.[^.]*+){2}\K.*//sr;      # 5.14+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you trust the IPs will come in a reasonable format, a really simple approach is just to cut off the last segment from the last `.`(dot) like so:

```
 my $ip = '10.9.8.x';
 (my $ipCore = $ip) =~ s/(.*?)\.[^.]+$/$1/;
 print $ipCore;
//yields '10.9.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

3 birds, 1 stone

```
my ($ip, $IPCore) = ("10.9.8.X");
print $IPCore if $ip =~ /([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){2})\.[xX]{1,3}$(?{$IPCore=$^N})/;
```

Out  `10.9.8`